# Same Footnotemark size all over the document

Tags: formatting, footnotes

Does anyone know how to get the same sized footnote symbol (number) in the titles of the document?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\part[]{Titel\footnote{Part footnote}}
\blindtext\footnote{Text footnote}
\section[]{Titel\footnote{Session footnote}}
\blindtext\footnote{Text footnote}
\end{document}
```

As you can see this makes the number for the `part` huge and for the `section` also rather big. I need all footnote numbers to be the same as in the main text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the macro responsible for typesetting the footnote mark:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@makefnmark{%
 \hbox{\ftntm@font\raisebox{\adjust@fnmheight}{\scriptsize\thefootnotemark}}%
}
\newcommand{\adjust@fnmheight}{%
  \dimexpr.85ex+.3\dimexpr\f@size pt-\basic@size pt\relax\relax
}
\AtBeginDocument{\edef\basic@size{\f@size}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\part[]{Titel\footnote{Part footnote}}
\blindtext\unskip\footnote{Text footnote}

\section[]{Titel\footnote{Session footnote}}
\blindtext\unskip\footnote{Text footnote}
\end{document}
```

The `.85ex` part raises the footnote mark just like `\textsuperscript` would do, in the normal size; but another shift up is applied depending on the current font size, precisely 3/10 of the difference between the current font size and the basic font size, so it will have no influence when normal text is being typeset. Adjust the fraction to your liking.

[image]