# Changing footnote number size in chapter heading

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, chapters, fontsize

I'm writing my thesis as book style and I formatted the chapter heading size with

```
\makeatletter % to set the layout of the chapters header
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{60\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
```

Now when I add a footnote to the chapter headings the footnote number is really big. How can I make it smaller?

Comment: A footnote iin a chapter title? Quite strange. I bet you are using the words in the title within the first few sentences of the chapter, place the footnote there.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193929/same-footnotemark-size-all-over-the-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as font size of chapter heading is `\huge`, the size of `footnotemark` tracking it, you can reduce size of `footnotemark` inside a group with `{\large\protect\footnote{text}}`

You can test it with this example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter % to set the layout of the chapters header
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{60\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        %\huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \huge\bfseries \thechapter.\space%
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter one{\Large\protect\footnote{footnote here}}}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

And the result

[image]

Comment: It should be `\chapter[Chapter one]{Chapter one{\Large\protect\footnote{footnote here}}}` or the footnote would appear also in the table of contents.